# How can i properly clone json array in redux?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, redux

Im new in Redux and Redux concepts look weird for me at first. Let say i have an array in redux state.

```
const state = [ 
  {show: false, id : '1'},
  {show: false, id : '2'},
  {show: false, id : '3'},
  {show: false, id : '4'},
  {show: false, id : '5'}
]
```

I want to clone this array and change/mutate one object.

I tried something like this in reducer but it did not work.

```
   return  [...state.concat(Object.assign({}, state[0], {show:true} )).slice(1,5)];
```

Any help or explanation would be nice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you might have switched `[]` with `{}` in your question.

Assuming your state is:

```
const state = [ 
  { show: false, id: '1' },
  { show: false, id: '2' },
  { show: false, id: '3' },
  { show: false, id: '4' },
  { show: false, id: '5' }
]
```

You can write a reducer like this:

```
return [
  ...state.slice(0, index),
  Object.assign({}, state[index], { /* your changes */ })
  ...state.slice(index + 1)
]
```

Where `index` is the index of the element you want to change.

#### References

- [Redux: Avoiding Array Mutations with concat(), slice(), and ...spread](https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-avoiding-array-mutations-with-concat-slice-and-spread)

Comment: I want to change first object in array, i tried this: 
return [...Object.assign({}, state[0], {show:true} ), ...slice(1,5)] 

It return just last 4 objetcs, first is missing...

Comment: It should be `...state.slice` in your case.

Comment: Still the same, it returns just 4 elements, first that i want to mutate is not in returned array... :(

Comment: Don't specify a length in your splice. Look at my example, just use `...state.slice(1)` to get the remaining array items.

Comment: It works now, i remove spread operator before Object.assign, looks like it is unnecessary. 

return [Object.assign({}, state[0], {show:true} ), ...state.slice(1)]

Comment: Glad I could help. Feel free to mark your question answered or let me know if you need something else! :)